# is it possible to Query an Odata service and expand Child of Child entities?

Tags: linq, odata, wcf-data-services

This sounds rather simple (and maybe I'm missing the obvious here) but I can't find a solution.  I know I can query an entity and return one, or many direct child entities doing this:

```
var query = from c in Service.Clients.Expand("Addresses,Comments,PhoneNumbers")..
```

What I would like to be able to do is do the same with 3 levels (Children of child), lets say "Country->Province->City" or "Brand->Family->Model"

I tried to expand all entities, but it fails

```
var query = from c in Service.Brands.Expand("Families,Models").. //fails,
//which even makes some sense, since Models is a Child of Family, not Brand
var query = from c in Service.Brands.Expand("Families").. //this works, 
//but Family.Models is empty
```

Is there a way to do this in one query, or do I have to split this in two separate queries?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The following statement should return what you are looking for:

```
var query = from c in Service.Brands.Expand("Families/Models")
```

This will run the following odata query:

```
.../OData.svc/Brands?$expand=Families/Models
```

[Here](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions#ExpandSystemQueryOption) is a link to some further odata documentation:

> The syntax of a $expand query option is a comma-separated list of Navigation Properties. Additionally each Navigation Property can be followed by a forward slash and another Navigation Property to enable identifying a multi-level relationship.

Comment: darn, I've read that ...but dismissed it rather quickly cause I had no idea what they meant with 'graph of entities' ... #$%$

 
 Thank you very much for pointing me, Gene

Comment: how do you make the select?

Comment: This syntax also works with the `QueryableExpandAttribute` https://gist.github.com/dbeattie71/7820af9f4ae4f68069207b49fc446c94 `[QueryableExpand("GrainBins,GrainBins/GrainBinLevelHistories")]`

Answer (score 34):

In ASP.NET OData v4, the URL convention seems to have changed. It is now:

```
~/Brands?$expand=Families($expand=Models)
```

You can also select the stuff you want in sub-entities.
For example if you want just the brand family identifiers:

```
~/Brands?$expand=Families($select=Id)
```

Furthermore, if you want only the identifiers of the brand family models, you would do that:

```
~/Brands?$expand=Families($expand=Models($select=Id))
```

...and so on. Hope this helps !

Comment: Does someone knows how to do this in Linq C# client??

Comment: @AndreasFurster Did you find out?

Comment: @LueTm Yes. If I remember it right the `.Expand(string entity)` method just adds `$expand=<entity param>` to the url query. So you could do: `.Expand("Families($expand=Models)")`. Yeah it's a 'little' bit ugly... But i though it will work.

Comment: the URL convention still uses slashes in odata v4: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398162

Comment: For anyone looking for this in pre v4 of oData you can use it like this instead: 
?$expand=Families/Models as mentioned in the specs https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/