# Web Api 2.2 with odata and $expand

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using codefirst with odata. I have setup my models and with relationships. The query seems to be working successfully. I am only running in an issue when using $expand when expanding nested data. I followed the following [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-$select,-$expand,-and-$value) off Microsoft's website. So I can do the following successfully

```
http://myurl.com/odata/catagories?$expand=Product
```

Now If i decide to go a level deeper usinng the following query

```
http://myurl.com/odata/catagories?$expand=Product/Supplier
```

I get the following error

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. Found a path traversing multiple navigation properties. Please rephrase the query such that each expand path contains only type segments and navigation properties.

If you visit the link above, someone in the comments seems to be having the same issue. I could swear I got this to work with a previous version of odata and Web Api.

Answer (score 38):

I found the answer after finding this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069882/is-it-possible-to-query-an-odata-service-and-expand-child-of-child-entities). @Rama provided the answer. I suggest Microsoft updates their docs on the link listed above. So instead of

```
http://myurl.com/odata/catagories?$expand=Product/Supplier
```

You would rather use

```
http://myurl.com/odata/catagories?$expand=Product($expand=Supplier)
```

Comment: The formal syntax is for OData V3, but later is for V4

Comment: the slash notation is odata v4: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata01/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata01-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc395267179

Comment: Particularly bad, because Microsoft claims it's implementing OData v4, and OData4 clients libraries will make the request using the Slash method. Rather than update the docs, Microsoft should update their implementation of Nested Expand.

Comment: @JamieButler That is not the case. According to the standard, the slash syntax is only used for complex types (types without keys), which Microsofts implementation supports.