# OData V4 more than one option in $expand

Tags: odata

in OData V4 inside an $expand query you can nest as an option:

1)$expand

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Categories?$expand=Products($expand=ProductDetail)
```

2)$levels

Entities($expand=ChildItems($level=x)) where ChildItem is the same type of Entity

3)$select

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Categories?$expand=Products($select=Price)&$select=Name,Products
```

I would like to expand ProductDetail like this but of course it does not work

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Categories?$expand=Products($expand=ProductDetail&$select=Price,ProductDetail)&$select=Name,Products
```

This call gets

> Query parameter '$select' is specified, but it should be specified exactly once

so you would think that you can $select only on the main entity but case #3 works perfectly.

I know that I could rewrite my query to achieve my objectives but I would like to know if this is possible.

Thanks,
Alessandro

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The key is the separator. You have to separate each option with ";".
I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28372712/3959304)

Case 3 becomes

> http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Categories?$expand=Products($select=Price,ProductDetail;$expand=ProductDetail)&$select=Name,Products