# Returning relational objects with oData and EFCore

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I can get relational data using linq and Entity framework core with the following controller function.  However, when I try to use oData it ignores the relational data.

Are there extra steps that I need to do?  There are no errors, but it just ignores the relational data in the response.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IEnumerable<User> Get()
    {
        IEnumerable<User> users;
        using (var context = new DivDbContext())
        {
            users = context.Users.Include(user => user.UserClaims).ToList();
        }

        return users;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  oData requires you to explicitly ask for expanded object via the URL.  I was able to do so by adding $expand=________ whatever property I wanted to expand.

https://localhost:44354/odata/users?$expand=userClaims

That said, I'm not sure how to handle nested properties with this syntax.  UserClaims has a claim property that would be nice to expand as well.

Comment: I can ask for multiple expanded properties on the same object using a forward slash, but I still have not found how to expand a property of an already expanded object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069882/is-it-possible-to-query-an-odata-service-and-expand-child-of-child-entities

Comment: Here is how you expand a child of a child:

Comment: https://localhost:44354/odata/users?$expand=userClaims($expand=claim)